# Get actual path symlink is pointing to

Tags: rust, symlink

Given a symlink, I want to know to which directory this symlink is pointing. Does the Rust standard library offer something to find this out?
I have only found [unstable API functions](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/trait.PathExt.html#method.symlink_metadata) so far.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It seems to me that you want [`fs::read_link`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/fn.read_link.html):

> Reads a symbolic link, returning the file that the link points to.

Answer (score 9):

You can use [`std::fs::canonicalize`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/fn.canonicalize.html):

> Returns the canonical, absolute form of a path with all intermediate
>   components normalized and symbolic links resolved.